# nullpointerexception run error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a java video poker game. When I run the test file, I get a nullpointexception error. It points to this line in my shuffling method `theDeck[i] = theDeck[j];`I'm still a novice in java...

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Deck {

private Card[] theDeck; 
private int top; 
// add more instance variables if needed

public Deck(){
    top = 0;
    Card[] theDeck = new Card[52];
    for(int s = 1; s <= 4; s++)
    {
        for (int v = 1; v <= 13; v++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < theDeck.length; i++)
            {

                theDeck[i] = new Card(s,v);
            }
        }
    }   
}

public void shuffle()
{
    // shuffle the deck here
    Random generator = new Random();
    int i;
    int j;
    i = generator.nextInt(51) + 1;
    j = generator.nextInt(51) + 1;
    Card temp = theDeck[i];
    for(int k = 1; k <100; k++)
    {
        theDeck[i] = theDeck[j];
        theDeck[j] = temp;
    }
    top = 0;
}
```

this is the part of the class that calls the  `shuffle` method:

```
public void play()
{
    cards.shuffle();
    for( int i =1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        p.addCard(cards.deal());
        cards.incrementTop();
    }
    for( int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        p.getHand().get(j).toString();
    }   
    System.out.println("These are your cards:");
    for( Card c : p.getHand())
    {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing the wrong `theDeck` array in your constructor.

In your constructor,

```
private Card[] theDeck; // Your constructor is not referring to this!
private int top; 
// add more instance variables if needed    

public Deck(){
        top = 0;
        Card[] theDeck = new Card[52]; // You defined a local theDeck variable!
        for(int s = 1; s <= 4; s++)
        {
            for (int v = 1; v <= 13; v++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < theDeck.length; i++)
                {

                    theDeck[i] = new Card(s,v);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

See what happened there? So instead of your constructor pointing to the class field `theDeck`, you created another one. So what you should do is remove the `Card[]` from that line so that your constructor points to the field, and you don't create a local variable.

Does that make sense? Make a comment so I can help you out further.

I also recommend that you make use of the `this` keyword to refer to your fields. This will help avoid confusion. See this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) for more on the `this` keyword.

Comment: Hi brain56. Thanks a lot for replying! Yes, I get it! I think I didn't notice it because the type of the variable is Card[]. If it was an int I think it would have been more clear. I'm really new to working with arrays/array lists. Thanks again :)

Comment: Alright, I'm glad to have helped! Java is really nice once you get the hang of it. If you can please accept my answer as the correct one, I'd appreciate the + in reps. :)

Comment: Just accepted as correct ;) But how do I do a + in reps?

Comment: Every time you accept someone's answer, you give them additional reputation (the number under my picture). If you really like their answer, you can also upvote their answer by pressing the upvote button (the up arrow on top  of the number beside the question). You can also upvote comments and questions. :)

Comment: You can make a new question about that and we'll see what we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

change `Card[] theDeck = new Card[52];` to `theDeck = new Card[52];`
You've already declared theDeck in your class, declaring it again in your constructor will reduce the scope of `theDeck` to be within the constructor. Also, the loop 
`for(int k = 1; k <100; k++)
    {
        theDeck[i] = theDeck[j];
        theDeck[j] = temp;
    }`

seems to not doing anything with the index `k`.

There's already a shuffle method available in the Collections API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html